# identifying position of the pattern match

Tags: python, regex

I need to find the exact position where the string matched..

```
>>> pattern = 'Test.*1'
>>> str1='Testworld1'
>>> match = re.search(pattern,str1)
>>> match.group()
'Testworld1'
```

I need the position of 1(10th byte) from the 'Testworld1' string which matched the pattern .*1.

Answer (score 6):

You want to do two things.  First make a group out of the `.*1`, then when accessing the group you can call `.start()`  Like so:

```
>>> pattern = 'Test.*(1)'
>>> match = re.search(pattern,str1)
>>> match.group(1)
'1'
>>> match.start(1)
9
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [`end()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end)

```
>>> pattern = r'Test.*1'
>>> str1='Testworld1'
>>> match = re.search(pattern,str1)
>>> match.end()
10
```

For more complicated applications (where you are not just looking for the last position of the last character in your match), you might want to use capturing and [`start`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) instead:

```
>>> pattern = r'Test.*(11)'
>>> str1='Testworld11'
>>> match = re.search(pattern,str1)
>>> match.start(1) + 1
10
```

Here, `start(n)` gives you the beginning index of the capture of the `n`th group, where groups are counted from left to right by their opening parentheses.